# Swift: Best way to store crypto amounts?

Tags: swift-language, floating-point

Having a bit of trouble on deciding the best way to store crypto values which are usually in decimals. Do I go with `Double` or `Float`? Or is there an even better type that Swift offers?

My initial gut feeling was `Float`, due to a constraint that I will have in the application (I won't even be dealing with amounts that are less than 0.15 Litecoin) and I thought that the double precision wouldn't be necessary, but cases may arise where I get values such as 0.1547378 and I want to handle them correctly, even though I am predicting that I will not see a number that requires 64 bits of precision.

If you have a suggestion, could you please give a brief explanation on why? I am looking to learn more.

Comment: You should read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken I think you have a misunderstanding of what precision means

Comment: Is it not the number of digits after the decimal? I will still read through the SO question though

Comment: Nope, not even close!

Comment: @Alexander It's an oversimplification but the number of places you display in a decimal is absolutely one of the (main) ways to confer precision.

Comment: @JimmyJames I think it crosses from mere "oversimplification" to "just wrong" for 2 reasons: 1) It expresses the precision as a number of decimal positions, not bits. Such estimations will be off by around 3.3x (`log(10)/log(2)`). 2) It ignores the fact the *the point is floating*, and makes it sound like the integral portion of the number has infinite precision, and only the decimal portion is truncated. In truth, the whole magnitude is subject to truncation.

Comment: And those aren't just pedantic theoretical qualms. Those oversimplications manifest themselves as the kind of confusions like what OP is currently experiencing

Comment: @Alexander Perhaps you are taking about the specifics of floating point precision but I read it as the concept of 'precision' in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add some information to [Jimmy's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/430071/209774).

If you still think that you can do financial calculations using Float or Double,  try this code snippet, that adds a couple of cents, one by one:

```
let iterations = 100
let fincrement: Float = 0.01
var fsum: Float = 0.0
for _ in 1...iterations {
    fsum = fsum + fincrement
}
print ("\(iterations) iterations with \(fincrement) float yields \(fsum)")
```

You'll be very surprised to find out that it'll be 0.99999934 with floats and 1.0000000000000007 with doubles.  The problem is not specific to swift, but floating point in general, and this [article explains it best](https://medium.com/the-technical-archaeologist/is-cobol-holding-you-hostage-with-math-5498c0eb428b).

Fortunately, you do not have to switch to COBOL to get it right. In many languages, you could work in cents using integer arithmetic.  But in swift, there's `Decimal`. It's slower but it's accurate, and can hold without loss very very large amounts:

```
let dcincrement = Decimal (1) / Decimal(100)
var dcsum = Decimal(0)
for _ in 1...iterations {
    dcsum = dcsum + dcincrement
}
print ("\(iterations) iterations with \(dcincrement) decimal yields \(dcsum)")
```

No surprise here: the result is exactly 1.

Answer (score 3):

I know nearly nothing about swift but it looks like that [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) is what you need.

Neither float nor double can represent all decimal values exactly because they use binary fractions: x0.1 = 1/2, x0.01 = 1/4, x0.001 = 1/8 etc.  If you had to use one, you should use double because the errors will be much less significant.  But since you have a decimal type available to you, I would recommend using it instead.

One other point: you need to be careful how you instantiate these.  If you use a float to create a decimal, the error in the float will copied into the decimal representation.  Usually you want to use a string representation as your init parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the same unit as the underlying cryptocurrency.

With dollars, we are advised to store cents because that is the actual smallest unit. Certain applications may want to store tenths of cents instead. In either case the software mirrors the reality. If your reality won't let you pay half a cent to someone, neither will your software. If you have a reality where people *can* pay tenth-cents, it would be a good idea to store tenth-cents. If you are worried it might change later, you can use a decimal type which makes it easier to add decimal places later.

In the case of Bitcoin, balances are stored as integer numbers of "Satoshi". 1 Bitcoin = 100,000,000 Satoshi. Satoshi are the smallest unit. You cannot have 0.5 Satoshi. So store your balances in Satoshi.

In the case of Litecoin it appears they inherited this design from Bitcoin and did not change it. It appears there is no official name but I have saw "photon" and "Litoshi". [Source 1](https://coincloud.medium.com/how-many-litoshi-makes-one-litecoin-cfa0568dc798) [Source 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/litecoin/comments/7kzh2o/what_is_the_satoshi_of_litecoin/) but you may choose to review the code yourself.

Again, if you think the system is likely to get more decimal places in the future, you can use a decimal type which makes it easier to add them.

Other cryptocurrencies may store balances differently.

Comment: that is a great point, I will incorporate this into the design. Although the other posters answered my specific question, this is what I ought to be doing. Thank you.

Comment: This gets to the root of it. Decimal representations are just syntactic or semantic sugar over integers where the system/compiler remembers the number of decimal places for you and ensures that you don't accidentally get the scaling wrong. But under the hood, it's always integral numbers of the smallest unit that you want to handle, so it's possible to just do it with integer arithmetics if you're careful.

Comment: Of course, if you choose to use a decimal type and the system decides to add more *binary* places... then you're lucky all binary fractions can be represented in decimal, but you're still stuck with the wrong type.

Answer (score -2):

You only use Float after a careful analysis that you have enough precision. Have you done that? If not, use Double. You always use Double unless you have a very good reason not to.

(As an example: Apple uses Double to represent screen coordinates -  because the found situations where Float was not enough and let to display errors. )